# JSch interrupt command executing

Tags: java, swing, jsch

I have swing application with two buttons for running and stopping executing of JSch command. 
So I have next method which invokes when we clicked on start button:

```
public String executeSSHCommand(String pattern, String listFiles) {             
    searchRez = new StringBuilder();        
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line, cmd = null;
    // adding ' symbol to pattern
    pattern = "'"+pattern+"'";       
    //
    try {
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");            
        cmd = "zgrep " + pattern + " " + listFiles;
        log.debug("Executing next ssh command: " + cmd);                        
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(cmd);                        
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);             
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        // read server output
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while(true && !isCancel){               
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !isCancel) {                        
            searchRez.append(line+"\n");                        
          }                         
          if(channel.isClosed()){
              log.debug("Exit status for execute ssh command is " + channel.getExitStatus());                
            break;
          }
          try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){log.error(ee);}
        }

        if (isCancel) {
            log.debug("Search was canceled by user... ");                

            channel.setInputStream(null);                
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
                br = null;
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){log.error(ee);}
        }
        //
        channel.disconnect();   
        session.disconnect();         
        log.debug("Search pattern in log file is complete.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex);
    }               
    log.debug("Rezult string has next value: " + searchRez.toString());
    return searchRez.toString();
}
```

As you can see above we have **isCancel** variable, it's boolean volatile variable which we set to false when click on stop button. So my problem is when user click on stop button and channel with sessions become disconnected, **zgrep** expression continue works on server. I thought that channel.disconnect() should stop all my running commands on server, could someone please advise how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@dic19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1795530/dic19) gave me an idea to send `Ctrl+C` command to server *before* disconnecting channel and session in order to interrupt `zgrep` command execution on server side.

I found [this post](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/mailman/jsch-users/thread/201204171444.XAA31684@jcraft.com/) in JSch mailing list which helped me to solve my problem.

So to send `Ctrl+C` command you should enable putty mode for channel object `((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);` and write `3` value to channel OutputStream:

```
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(cmd);                        
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);             
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        channel.connect();
        ...........
        if (isCancel) {
            log.debug("Search was canceled by user... ");                

            channel.setInputStream(null);                
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
                br = null;
            }
            out.write(3);
            out.flush();
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){log.error(ee);}
        }
```

Comment: +1 But please add the code that solved your problem, so in case the link is dropped your answer still complete. Besides future visitors won't have to navigate to external sources to find the answer.

Comment: CTRL+C is not signal 3, that is SIGQUIT. SIGINT is 2, see [man-page of signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting pty to true, you may also simply use:

```java
((ChannelExec) channel).sendSignal("INT"); // may throw Exception
```

This works even after you have already called `out.close();` (out relates to the `stdin` of the running command).